# WeakValueDictionary retaining reference to object with no more strong references

Tags: python, mapping, python-2.7, weak-references

```
>>> from weakref import WeakValueDictionary
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> db = WeakValueDictionary()
>>> db['foo-id'] = foo
>>> del foo
>>> dict(db)
{'foo-id': <__main__.Foo object at 0x4dd946c>}
```

Why does it show this instead of an empty dictionary? Note that this code produces the result I'd expect:

```
>>> db2 = WeakValueDictionary()
>>> db2['disposable-id'] = Foo()
>>> dict(db2)
{}
```

It also behaves as expected when executing a script (instead of the interactive interpreter):

```
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary
class Foo(object):
    pass
foo = Foo()
db = WeakValueDictionary()
db['foo-id'] = foo
del foo
print str(dict(foo))
# prints {}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`WeakValueDictionary` does not guarantee that entries will be removed when there are no normal references. What it guarantees is that it will not prevent garbage collection in due course - your object is *garbage collectable*, not *garbage collected*. The entry will disappear when garbage collection happens.

Answer (score 4):

If you have only been trying this in an interactive shell, I believe it has to do with the way the garbage collection is working under that interface and the global scope operations.

Try this from a script:

**foo.py**

```
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary

class Foo(object):
    pass

f = Foo()
d = WeakValueDictionary()
d['f'] = f 

print dict(d)
del f 
print dict(d)
```

And then...

```
$ python foo.py

{'f': <__main__.Foo object at 0x101f496d0>}
{}
```

Now, try this from an interactive python shell, moving the operation under a functions scope:

```
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary

class Foo(object):
    pass

f = Foo()
d = WeakValueDictionary()
d['f'] = f 

def main():
    global f
    print dict(d)
    del f 
    print dict(d)

main()

#{'f': <__main__.Foo object at 0x100479f10>}
#{}
```

Comment: I also tried importing `gc` in the interactive interpreter and calling `gc.collect()` after `del`ing `foo` and it eliminated the weak reference. Apparently the interactive interpreter does not collect garbage immediately.

Comment: Ya. Without have a scientific answer, I would say simply that the interactive shell isnt the best case for realiable behavior. Its great for testing but cant be beat by a simple executable script.

Answer (score 3):

In Python Interactive Shell, whatever variable you declare, is not garbage collected automatically, since the scope in `__main__` has not ended. Garbage collection in Python is based on **reference count**, and until you do it explicitly or get off the current scope, it won't be collected.

In same shell, if you implement your `WeakRef` logic inside function, you will see the expected result, since upon finishing function, controls gets out of scope and objects are collected by garbage.

That's why example by @jdi with function is showing you exactly what you want.