# Python WeakValueDictionary retains values after gc.collect() in IPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, garbage-collection, ipython

I'm trying to understand Python `weakref` module and its use cases, so I have the following setup:

```
import gc, weakref

class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self._s = "Sample" if not val else " ".join(["Sample:", str(val)])
    def sample(self):
        return self._s

ol = [obj(x) for x in range(1,4)]
o1 = obj(1)
o2 = obj(2)
o3 = obj(3)

wdict1 = weakref.WeakValueDictionary({k:ol[k-1] for k in range(1,4)})

wdict2 = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
wdict2[1] = o1
wdict2[2] = o2
wdict2[3] = o3
```

After running my tests I can clearly see, that `WeakValueDictionary` somehow has retained all the values, even though I have explicitly called `gc.collect()`. To my understanding and as explained in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12024510/2146346), calling `gc.collect()` should remove all weakly referenced values.

```
In [2]: wdict1.items()
Out[2]: 
[(1, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0be90>),
 (2, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bf10>),
 (3, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bf50>)]

In [3]: wdict2.items()
Out[3]: 
[(1, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c51790>),
 (2, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bed0>),
 (3, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bf90>)]

In [4]: del ol[0]

In [5]: del o1

In [6]: gc.collect()
Out[6]: 64

In [7]: wdict1.items()
Out[7]: 
[(1, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0be90>),
 (2, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bf10>),
 (3, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bf50>)]

In [8]: wdict2.items()
Out[8]: 
[(1, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c51790>),
 (2, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bed0>),
 (3, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bf90>)]

In [9]: del ol[0]

In [10]: del o2

In [11]: gc.collect()
Out[11]: 0

In [12]: wdict1.items()
Out[12]: 
[(1, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0be90>),
 (2, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bf10>),
 (3, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bf50>)]

In [13]: wdict2.items()
Out[13]: 
[(1, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c51790>),
 (2, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bed0>),
 (3, <__main__.obj at 0x7fea09c0bf90>)]

In [14]: weakref.getweakrefs(ol[0])
Out[14]: [<weakref at 0x7fea0ab05470; to 'obj' at 0x7fea09c0bf50>]

In [15]: weakref.getweakrefs(o3)
Out[15]: [<weakref at 0x7fea09c060b0; to 'obj' at 0x7fea09c0bf90>]

In [16]: wdict1[1].sample()
Out[16]: 'Sample: 1'

In [17]: wdict2[2].sample()
Out[17]: 'Sample: 2'
```

What's wrong with my code, why all the weakly referenced values were kept?

Comment: It works fine for me, are you sure you did not keep reference to `o1` or any of the objects from `ol` in some other name? Try same after restarting the python session

Comment: I use `ipython 2.3.0`. So I open new console and `%cpaste` my *setup* code, then copy/paste my testing code - the output is above. There are no other variables nor modules loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that IPython keeps references to your objects using the following -

1. [`_`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#history) - result of last statement.
2. [`__`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#history) - result of second last statement.
3. [`___`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#history) - result of third last statement.
4. [`In[num]`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#history) - string of the statement that run for prompt number `num`
5. [`Out[num]`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#history) - result/output of the prompt number `num` statement.

From [documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#history) -

> Input and output history are kept in variables called `In` and `Out`, keyed by the prompt numbers, e.g. `In[4]`. The last three objects in output history are also kept in variables named `_`, `__` and `___`.

You can actually try running `Out[2]` and see that it would be the reference to the result of `wdict1.items()` (if in `2` prompt number you ran that statement as you have given in your example).

IPython is most probably keeping alot of such references to your object, hence when you delete one of the names like `ol[0]` or `o1` , and then do `gc.collect` . It does not actually collect the object , since there are still references to the object (in `_` or `__` or `___` or `Out[num]` ).

Two solutions I can think of -

1. Use [`%xdel`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-xdel) magic command to remove the reference, like `%xdel ol[0]` , instead of `del ol[0]` . This would cause IPython to clear out all references it keeps as well. Based on [documentation -](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-xdel)

> Delete a variable, trying to clear it from anywhere that IPython’s machinery has references to it.

2. You can try running this tests as a script ,instead of interactively, in that case these extra references would not be created, and you should see the correct behavior.

Comment: You are right, it has to do with `ipython`... I just have tried the same code on plain `python` interpreter and it worked just fine. Thanks. However your `%xdel` workaround doesn't work very well with lists, gives me an error: `NameError: name 'ol[0]' is not defined`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yea, I guess it does not work on list objects. But does your real usecase also need you to run this interactively?

Comment: No, not really interactively, I just like to try new things interactive and I find 'ipython' a very good tool for that. The best workaround I've found so far is to run script-file via `execfile()` in `ipython`, then variables are updated as expected.